# Grow from center

Tags: animation, css

I have been trying to get the bottom circles to grow in Firefox (need to add in other prefixes, still in dev)

They are behaving properly, but my goal is to get them to grow from the center. Any ideas on how i can use CSS to do that? Would it be a positioning thing? The link is here: http://www.catonthecouch.com/feline/

I am simply growing the width/height on hover.

Comment: I see you got your answer. Just want to say I love your company name & logo! Cats FTW :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add negative left and top margins equal to half of the change in size (`-15px`)

Comment: Check it out now. That does look much better but it jumps at first. thoughts?

Comment: bingo, had it on the wrong one. thank you

Comment: You should probably also keep the content centered.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using CSS3, you can use the property transform, and scale the element.

*Obs: I have omitted the prefixes to avoid too much code, but you should use them.*

```
.circle {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: scale(0.1); /* 1/10 of the original size */
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.circle.opened {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JCMais/eKs59/

Comment: In the working demo (very nice, by the way), did you mean some of your transitions to be 0.5s and some 2.0s ?

Comment: That was not intended @den232, all of them should be 0.5

Comment: Thanks.    I got it now.  jb