# CSS Animation Timing

Tags: css

I'm having a hard time making this preloader animation in CSS.

This is what I'm trying to make.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
.l {
  animation: pulse .8s infinite linear;
}
.m {
  animation: pulse .8s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
.r {
  animation: pulse .8s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%   { padding: 8px; }
  50% { padding: 16px; }
  100%  { padding: 8px; }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0 0.6em;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.l {
  animation: pulse .8s infinite linear;
}
.m {
  animation: pulse .8s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
.r {
  animation: pulse .8s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%   { padding: 8px; }
  50% { padding: 16px; }
  100%  { padding: 8px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="circle l"></div>
    <div class="circle m"></div>
    <div class="circle r"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please have a look at this too..just for fun https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/j4tj5pg8/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`step-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#step-end):

```
animation: pulse .8s infinite step-end;
```

```css
body{
  padding-top: 40px; /* for demonstration purpose */
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0 0.6em;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.l {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite step-end;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
.m {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite step-end;
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
.r {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite step-end;
  animation-delay: .6s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%   { transform: scale( 1 ); }
  50% { transform: scale( 2 ); }
  100%  { transform: scale( 1 ); }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="circle l"></div>
    <div class="circle m"></div>
    <div class="circle r"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/us72ktz6/1/)

Now just adjust the animation duration and delay time to make it more like in the OP.

Update: use `transform: scale()` to make the circle expand from its centar - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897208/grow-from-center)

Comment: Nice try but in your fiddle whole structure is moving but in op's gif its only one circle which is moving. Please check back.

Comment: @Leothelion yea, didn't notice that - updated the answer.

Comment: I forgot about [step-end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#step-end), which reminded me of [Lea Verou's](http://lea.verou.me/projects/) project [cubic-bezier.com](http://cubic-bezier.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I have extra frames to the animation. Check below answer.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.l {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite linear;
}
.m {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: .3s;
}
.r {
  animation: pulse 2s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  10% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1.7);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.7);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.7);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="circle l"></div>
    <div class="circle m"></div>
    <div class="circle r"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```